# Couchbase: Retrieving newly added or recently updated documents from the bucket

Tags: couchbase

How can I set Observables to listen to different events from a bucket? So that whenever a new document added to the bucket or existing document updated I can read them and push it to the destination.

Note: Just getting started with couchbase.

Comment: Are you looking for when any document is updated or a specific one is updated?

Comment: Any document is updated.

Answer (score 1):

Right now the SDK doesn't offer an API to listen to changes in the database. This is something that might be built as a facade on top of DCP, the protocol for cross data center replication, at a later point in time

Answer (score 1):

To add more to what Simon said, you might be able to write your own DCP connector. DCP does provide the stream of changes you are looking for, but you have to have a connector that will ingest that stream. If this is something you might be up for, i'd look at the code for existing connectors like the [Kafka connector](http://docs.couchbase.com/sdk-api/couchbase-kafka-connector-1.0.0/com/couchbase/kafka/package-summary.html) and see if you could use them to create your own.

Answer (score 1):

As Kirk said, you can definitely use DCP for this, as long as you're ok with writing it in Java, because that's the only SDK that currently has (experimental) support for streaming document changes.

As it happens, David Maier wrote a step-by-step tutorial on how to implement a change notification listener for Couchbase: http://nosqlgeek.blogspot.co.il/2015/05/dcp-magic.html